# Color issue on chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I got stuck in a weird issue i am only seeing in chrome. Can some one please try to replicate it and let me know if its not only me.

I have MacBook Pro 2015 (Retina). When i use the following code on my laptop screen it shows fine. However as soon as i drag it onto my external monitor the color shows up quite differently. Probably a bug in chrome browser?

Here is the code:

```
<html>
    <body style="background: #c59595;">
        Strange colors
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is what i see: 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem. Open System `Preferences -> Display` and go to the monitor where you have this issue. Click on the tab `Color` and click `Calibrate`. Go through that multi-step process with all the settings as the default ones, and then your issue will be fixed.